# Free Windows software for animations

Tags: software-recommendation, animation, free, windows

Can anyone suggest a good (and easy to use) freeware for creating animations in Windows? I was looking at the [Pencil](http://www.pencil-animation.org/) mentioned in a [similar question](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/76/what-programs-can-be-used-to-make-animations), but it seems its development has stopped. In addition, I'd like to export the output animations directly in the GIF or FLV format rather than SWF or QuickTime. I know it's possible to export PNGs from the Pencil and put them together with the other tool, but I would appreciate this feature. I'm looking for something like Animation Shop, but freeware.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://synfig.org/

you can try this

Comment: +1 and accept, looks pretty well and it seems still alive, thanks a lot :)